# How to get MSA user to work as an App Pool Identity? (Getting error 503)

Tags: windows, iis

I'm trying to switch to an MSA account instead of normal user account.

I got a domain user as MSA: `my-domain\msa_account$`.

I created a new application pool with identical settings to the existing and working application pool.

I added the user to the local users group and also added it to the `Log on as a batch job` list in `secpol`

I then added this user to the users of the website folder and gave him the same permissions.

In the app pool I set this user as the identity user like so: `msa_account$`, left password blank and clicked ok.

Added a website to this application pool.

But then I get error 503, service unavailable, and the app pool stopped.

What can else can it be? Do I need to restart anything at some point? The server? IIS? What setting did I forget?

Comment: The identity might need to be specified as `domain\account$`.

Comment: I am going to try soon as I'm not there right now, but from what I remember, when I use a regular account, then if I enter a wrong password for the custom user, it will throw an error when I click "OK" after trying to add the identity. But with the domain user, it let me put any password I want or blank and it accepts it. Could it be that the account itself has a password as well but because it doesn't prompt about wrong passwords so I later get the error?

Comment: OMG @harrymc YOU WERE CORRECT! `domain\account$` worked!!! If you want you can write an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for the poster was the way that the account was used.
The correct syntax is:

```
domain\account$
```

The syntax of `account$` is accepted by IIS, but may be used as a
local account.

Comment: Perfect! That worked. And just to update: I removed the user completely from the server, so it is not a local user, and I also removed it from the `Log on as a batch job` options in `secpol`. So it's now only a domain user which doesn't exist on the server and it's working